# How to receive offline messages in group chat from ejabbered in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, chat, xmppframework

I had implemented group chat, which is working fine. But problem is that:
**how can i receive offline message when user goes out from group**.
I had tried, When i set status of user to `unavailable` from group/chat session, the ejabbered doesn't store messages for that user. 
And even doesn't store message in `spool` table.

Anyone please share some stuff!

Thanks!

Comment: This may be the answer to your question:  
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508250/ejabberd-muc-message-history>

Answer (score 0):

Query to server with date parameter from current date to your desire past date .

Comment: the issue is with notification from server, it works perfect in one-one chat but not in case of group chat(MUC).

Comment: Use multicast for group chat not MUC for sending message in a group.